# Buffer overflow using snprintf

Tags: c, buffer

This is an assignment but I am having problems with the basic understanding.

The vulnerable code:

```
int choc(char *arg)
{
  char buf[400];
  snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, arg);
  return 0;
}
```

I understand that arg needs to be a format string which will overwrite the return address with the address of the code I want to execute. But I am having trouble creating the format string.

So, things which the format string needs to have:

1. the address of the return instruction, which I need to overwrite
2. A list of %x
3. The value which I would write on the return address. This would be the address of the code I want to execute.

In order to get the return address, I just need to look at the address of the 'ret' instruction in gdb right? What exactly is the purpose to the %x? And how do I encode the address of the code I want to execute in the format string?

A test I did:
Using gdb I found that the address of my buf is 0xbffffba0. I generated arg to be "\xa0\xfb\xff\xbf_%x.%x.%n"; Shouldn't this write some value to the start of the buff at the address 0xbffffba0? However I get a segfault. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't feel like writing an answer, but I just did this assignment. For those coming after me, I got it working by overwriting `__DTOR_END__` byte by byte. You'll end up using almost all of the bytes allotted to you by the snprintf call, but you can do it in time and jump into `arg`, which should have your shellcode on the end of it. I followed the first part of the explanation in this link to get me started: https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/28476.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The `"\xa0\xfb\xff\xbf"` should not be the address of buf, but rather the location of the return address on the stack (which is the value you wish to overwrite). You'll have to find that value using gdb.

You then need to put enough %x in your format string such that your %n will read that value off the stack and write to the address you specified. You also need to to use the correct field sizes such that %n will actually write the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

Vulnerability you are trying to exploit is called format string vulnerability.
For further investigation on this topic I would recommend [THIS](http://www.google.si/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=format%20string%20vulnerability&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CD4QFjAB&url=http://crypto.stanford.edu/cs155old/cs155-spring08/papers/formatstring-1.2.pdf&ei=mOOFT4GxFsHzsgb-gpHUBg&usg=AFQjCNG3QiG2k0n39PsNfLIcyjkiZJjuow&cad=rja) link or book called "Hacking: art of exploitating".

Comment: Yes, I read that link. And I believe I am doing exactly what it is telling me to. However instead of writing to buff, I get a segfault. Not sure why

Comment: Well, I'm not sure but your problem is probably connected with some exploits countermeasuers that are built-in in newer versions of linux, such as "non-executable stack"

Comment: @Catie- It's possible that you're going too far and causing `snprintf` to access memory past the end of the stack.  Step through the function on the assembly level and you should be able to see if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the value out of the debugger is generally not sufficient.  Some platforms have address space randomization security features that will cause the address of a particular object to differ between program invocations.  Instead, you'll want to find out where on the stack the return address is stored (relative to the `snprintf` call) and overwrite it there.  This is very CPU-specific.  For what platform are you developing?

Using the debugger, step through the code for that function on the assembly level and inspect the stack just before the `return` command is encountered.  Make sure that the stack and the return address look like you think they should look.  This should give you a clue as to where the problem is.  Also, you can try manually modifying the stack with the debugger just before the `return` in order to verify that the location that you're targeting is actually the return address.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is no, you don't just need the address of the 'ret' instruction. What you actually need is the location in memory that the 'ret' instruction loads. Have a look at this diagram:

http://post.queensu.ca/~trd/377/tut5/stack.html

You are aiming to overwrite the 'Return Address'.

I'll go ahead and try to write a short program to show this pointer (to come).

**Update:** I have bad news. I can't figure it out either. I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void bar()
{
    printf("Bar function\n");
}

void foo()
{
    void (**p)(void);
    asm volatile("movl %%ebp, %0\n\t" : "=r"(p) : : "%0");
    p += 1;
    *p = bar;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Which causes a Segmentation fault without printing the sentence in `bar()`. I would expect it to work... so now I'm just as confused as you are. Can anyone explain why `bar()` doesn't execute in my code?

Comment: Thanks! So is the return address is saved in %eip? In gdb, I did 'info frame' and saw the saved address of %eip, and created a string same as above, just with that address swapped over. Always a seg fault. I am just trying to make it write anywhere without a seg fault (that is why chose the start of the buff).